# How to register a JavaScript function from a dynamically built ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dynamic

I have an **ASP.NET** page named **SP.aspx** and from this page I am calling some **JavaScript** code in **DT.js** via a button click. Inside this **DT.js** file I am building a dynamic html page called **StDT.aspx**.

My problem is that the **StDT.aspx** page also has a **JavaScript** function attached to `button_click`. When I click the button in **StDT.aspx** I am getting the error:

> button_click function not defined.

How do I register this **JavaScript** function in **StDT.aspx** and where do I register as I don't have a .cs codefile tied this page.

Comment: Welcome to SO SATY ... could you post the code that's not working?  It's very difficult to figure out how to fix something without seeing the code that actually needs the fixing.

Comment: There is no reason to build a `.aspx` file inside JavaScript, as you can't build server-side code on the client side and have it execute. The dynamic html page you are building should be vanilla html. Though I would rethink the logic and perhaps have the javascript do an AJAX call that returns dynamically built HTML from the server.

Comment: THanks for your help. I am building .aspx page instead of JavaScript.